# How to change value of nested JSON with Vue $set?

Tags: json, vue.js

```
[
  {
    "id": 1, 
    "question": "Top Level question", 
    "answers": [
      {"id" : 1, "isSelected" : false}, 
      {"id" : 2, "isSelected" : true}, 
      {"id" : 3, "isSelected" : false}, 
      {"id" : 4, "isSelected" : false}, 
      {"id" : 5, "isSelected" : false}, 
      {"id" : 6, "isSelected" : false}
    ],
    "MaxAllowedChoice" : 1,
    "isEnabled" : true,
    "NowSelected" : 0
  }
]
```

I wrote next loop:

```
for (let question of this.questions) {
  //console.log(question.answers); // array of answers

  for(let answer of question.answers) {
    //this.$set('answer.isSelected', true);
    console.log('Before: ', answer.isSelected);
    // this.$set('answer.isSelected', true); //warning: You are setting a non-existent path "answer.isSelected"
    this.$set('questions.answers.answer.isSelected', true);  // so look like I should to do like this to change value
    // this.$set('questions.answers.answer.isSelected', true); //I can't understand how to write it's correctly... like this or above. 
    console.log('After: ', answer.isSelected);
  }
}
```

I need to change all values to true (or is it's possible to change true<->false and vice versa). I can't understand how to reach needed key.
`this.$set('answer.isSelected', true);` produce warning, and look like it can't undestand what key it should change.

`this.$set('questions.answers.answer.isSelected', true);` do not produce warining, but I am not sure that it's change value in right place.
Because I see in console:

> Before:  false
>   After:   false
>   Before:  true
>   After:   true

But all values in my code should be set to true.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you shouldn't need to use `this.$set()`. You should be able to set the property directly on the current answer in each iteration:

```
for(let question of this.questions) {
    for(let answer of question.answers) {
        answer.isSelected = true;
    }
}
```

If you really need to use `$set()` (which might make sense in some scenarios), you'll have to use the array indexes in the keypath:

```
this.$set('questions[0].answers[0].isSelected', true);
```